# Network Flow - qualities of saturated edges

Tags: graphs, network-flow, minimum-cuts

While I know that every edge is fully saturated in every min-cut of a network flow, I'm trying to get some intuition when the converse is true.
I can find an example using edges with infinite capacity, but is there any way to generalize this idea?

Are there graphs where every saturated edge is part of some min-cut?

### EDIT

So after drawing some graphs, I'm able to get the general idea that whenever a path connected-circle(in the undirected graph)  contains this saturated edge, and the path contains another saturated edge, it can be part of a min-cut since I can "cut" the graph along this axis.

So far, I've been looking at smaller graphs and proving this for a simple graph containing only one circle. Can this be generalized further?

Comment: *"Are there graphs where every saturated edge is part of some min-cut?"* - I recommend you try some examples of small graphs, say with 2, 3, 4 vertices, see what patterns you can find, and see if you can use that to answer your question, then [edit] your question or write an answer to your own question.